# Parsing Email returning com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException exception

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap, incoming-mail

I have one requirement for parsing all email from one of gmail account.

My code is below

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
            session.addProvider(new Provider(Provider.Type.STORE, "gimaps", "com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore","Oracle","1.5.4"));
            GmailSSLStore store = (GmailSSLStore) session.getStore("gimaps");
            store.connect(user, password); <--- ERROR 
            GmailFolder folder = (GmailFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

I have tried many ways by added all required properties `mail.smtp.*` but still i get below error

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:725)
    at com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore.protocolConnect(GmailStore.java:92)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
    at com.rs.utils.ReceiveMail.receiveEmail(ReceiveMail.java:88)
    at com.rs.thread.ScheduleMailParsing.parsingMail(ScheduleMailParsing.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:123)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:126)
    at com.sun.mail.gimap.protocol.GmailProtocol.<init>(GmailProtocol.java:106)
    at com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore.newIMAPProtocol(GmailStore.java:98)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:684)
    ... 20 more
```

This code is working fine in my local machine but when i deploy war file into tomcat server at that time i got this exception..

my tomcat server is from MOCHAHOST hosting server.

anyone know how to solve this exception?

Comment: Looks like an network issue. Can you reach the IMAP server with a ping from command line?

Comment: The FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Most likely there's a firewall preventing you from connecting directly.